# Getting Graphs from Mathematica to Latex

Tags: graphics, latex

In my Mathematica notebook, I have a matrix of graphs which I want to put as a table of graphs into a Latex file. The way I usually do it take a screenshot of each of the graphs and put them as a table in Latex but this time I have a lot of graphs so I was wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: Can you, please, give an example image of what you would intend for it to look like? Equally importantly would be to have some sort of an example of the graphs in the mathematics format you have them in. That is, please post some example code for other users to work with when trying to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I actually figured out how to do it but I'll make sure to do this for my other questions.

Comment: You should self-answer your question :) and I recommend making the improvements anyways, so that others may possibly show you better methods than the one you will answer yourself with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting `m` be your matrix of graphs:

```
ctr = 0;
t = StringTemplate["plt``.pdf"];
Do[Do[Export[t[++ctr],plt], {plt, row}], {row, m}]
```